# Plotting a times series using matplotlib with 24 hours on the y-axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

If I run the following, it appears to work as expected, but the y-axis is limited to the earliest and latest times in the data. I want it to show midnight to midnight. I thought I could do that with the code that's commented out. But when I uncomment it, I get the correct y-axis, yet nothing plots. Where am I going wrong?

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = ['2018-01-01 09:28:52', '2018-01-03 13:02:44', '2018-01-03 15:30:27', '2018-01-04 11:55:09']
x = []
y = []

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    t = datetime.strptime(data[i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    x.append(t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) # X-axis = date
    y.append(t.strftime('%H:%M:%S')) # Y-axis = time

plt.plot(x, y, '.')
# begin = datetime.strptime('00:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').strftime('%H:%M:%S')
# end   = datetime.strptime('23:59:59', '%H:%M:%S').strftime('%H:%M:%S')
# plt.ylim(begin, end)
plt.show()
```

Edit: I also noticed that the x-axis isn't right either. The data skips Jan 2, but I want that on the axis so the data is to scale.

This is a dramatically simplified version of code dealing with over a year's worth of data with over 2,500 entries.

Comment: With Python 3.6 your code throws an error for me: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2018-01-01'`

Comment: @andrew_reece: The commented code? Strange that I don't get an error with Python 3.6.2. No matter. Seems I'm throwing out that ugly code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Pandas is available to you, consider this approach:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.to_datetime(data, yearfirst=True)
plt.plot(data.date, data.time)
_=plt.ylim(["00:00:00", "23:59:59"])
```

[image: plot]

**Update** per comments
X-axis date formatting can be adjusted using the `Locator` and `Formatter` methods of the `matplotlib.dates` module.  `Locator` finds the tick positions, and `Formatter` specifies how you want the labels to appear.

Sometimes Matplotlib/Pandas just gets it right, other times you need to call out exactly what you want using these extra methods.  In this case, I'm not sure why those numbers are showing up, but this code will remove them.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

f, ax = plt.subplots()
data = pd.to_datetime(data, yearfirst=True)
ax.plot(data.date, data.time)
ax.set_ylim(["00:00:00", "23:59:59"])

days = mdates.DayLocator()
d_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(d_fmt)
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: This fixes both axes with much simpler code. Thank you! Just one issue: How do I limit the x-axis to single dates? I'm not sure what those in-between dates with 13's are doing there.

Comment: You're welcome.  See updated answer for adjustments to x-axis tick labels.

Comment: This is perfect... except I want dots, not lines. I'm so lost in this code right now I'm not even sure how to do that. I assumed plt.plot(data.date, data.time, '.') would be sufficient, but that plots dots *and* lines.

I'm sure I'll sort through this and understand it better at some point. Thank you again for your very useful help!

Comment: Got it. It just needed ax.plot(data.date, data.time, '.') and an omission of plt.plot(...)

Comment: You can also use `ax.plot_date()` to get dots.